# Delete files with (1) or (2) when without it exists

Tags: bash

my photo libary is a total mess.
I have images that looks like this because of some copys:

```
IMG_20220505_1701.jpg
IMG_20220505_1701 (1).jpg
IMG_20220505_1701 (2).jpg
```

Now I want to delete every photo that contains (1) or (2) in his name, but only, when a file without it exists.
How can I do this?

Comment: I am not sure about bash, but my approach would be to write a short C++ program and move files to another folder instead of deleting them (just to be safe). I would suggest that, but I don't know if you are familiar with C. That would be a "practical" solution for me

Comment: I am not familiar with c

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could do something like:

```
rename-or-delete() {
  if [[ -e $2 ]]; then
    rm -- $1
  else
    mv -- $1 $2
  fi
}
autoload zmv
zmv -n -f -P rename-or-delete '(*) \(<->\)(.jpg)' '$1$2'
```

(remove the `-n` for dry-run if happy).

Answer (score 5):

This will delete all files with numbers in parentheses in their names if a file without the number exists:

```bash
for file in *'('* ; do 
    origFile=$(sed 's/ *([0-9]*)//' <<<"$file")
    [ -e "$origFile" ] && [ "$file" != "$origFile" ] && rm -- "$file"
done
```

Note that in the case where a file without the numbmers does not exist, this will keep all number files. So, for example, if you have `somefile (1).png` and `somefile (2).png` but do not have `somefile.png`, then both `somefile (1).png` and `somefile (2).png` will be kept. If that can be an issue, after running the command above, you can rename all `(1)` files with `perl-rename` (called `rename` on Ubuntu and other Debian based distributions):

```
rename -- 's/ \(1\)//' *'(1)'*
```

And then run the first command again to only keep one. You may need to play around a bit if you also have cases where only the `(2)` or `(N)` file exists.

Answer (score -6):

Not exactly what you asked for (and untested) but I think it's in the same spirit:

```
#!/bin/sh
last=x
for i in * ; do
  if [ -f "$i" ] ; then
    if cmp "$last" "$i" ; then
      rm -f "$i"
    else
      last="$i"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Rather than deleting duplicate filenames, this deletes consecutive files with identical contents.

Comment: Please do test before posting. This has very many problems. First, since you're not quoting properly, it will fail on the OP's file names which contain whitespace. Second, it will complain on the first iteration unless there is a file named `x`. Third, it is assuming that the files will be returned in order which is not guaranteed, and is guaranteed not to happen if you can have double-digit numbers. Fourth, it will keep the bad file names, the ones with the `(N)` and not the original. It will also fail on file names beginning with a `-`, but that's less likely to be an issue.

Comment: missed one, fixed.  If you see other problems, fix it or rewrite it and post your own answer.

Comment: This still keeps the wrong file. The OP wants to delete the files with the parentheses, not keep them.

Comment: this does a different thing though, in that it compares the files, instead of just checking at the names. And hence it would delete `b.txt` if `a.txt` and `b.txt` exist and are identical. And like terdon says, names like `foo (1).txt` and `foo.txt` sort in the wrong order for this to work (the ones with a number before the one without). `ls -v` with GNU ls prints them in the right order, though.